# JBoss EAP 6.3 + cxf 2.7.11 jax-rs causes

Tags: java, web-services, jboss, cxf, jax-rs

I am trying to deploy REST API on JBoss EAP 6.3 using jax-rs implementation based on cxf 2.7.11 that I provide in WAR archive. Currently I am getting following error when I call non existing URL (404 expected):

```
12:22:14,627 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/my-app-1.0-SNAPSHOT].[CXFServlet]] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-2) JBWEB000236: Servlet.service() for servlet CXFServlet threw exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.ClientErrorException.validate(Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Response;Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Response$Status$Family;)Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Response;
at javax.ws.rs.ClientErrorException.<init>(ClientErrorException.java:127) [javax.ws.rs-api-2.0-m10.jar:2.0-m10]
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.SpecExceptions.toHttpException(SpecExceptions.java:110) [cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.ExceptionUtils.toHttpException(ExceptionUtils.java:149) [cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils.findTargetMethod(JAXRSUtils.java:477) [cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor.processRequest(JAXRSInInterceptor.java:196) [cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor.handleMessage(JAXRSInInterceptor.java:88) [cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272) [cxf-api-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121) [cxf-api-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:241) [cxf-rt-transports-http-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:248) [cxf-rt-transports-http-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:222) [cxf-rt-transports-http-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:153) [cxf-rt-transports-http-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:171) [cxf-rt-transports-http-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:286) [cxf-rt-transports-http-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doGet(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:211) [cxf-rt-transports-http-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:262) [cxf-rt-transports-http-2.7.13.jar:2.7.13]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:231) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169) [jboss-as-web-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:145) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:926) [jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.4.8.Final-redhat-4]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09]
```

I tried to exclude resteasy in jboss-deployment-structure.xml but it doesn't help:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
    <deployment>
        <exclude-subsystems>
            <subsystem name="resteasy" />
            <subsystem name="jaxrs" />
            <subsystem name="webservices" />
        </exclude-subsystems>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="javax.ws.rs.api" />
            <module name="org.apache.cxf" />
            <module name="org.apache.cxf.impl" />
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

CXF version 2.6.16 works fine.

I guess there is a problem with javax.ws.rs-api-2.0-m10 which is transitive dependency of cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs, but when I exclude this I am getting ClassNotFoundException's for jax-rs API specific classes.

Is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: Do you have an additionally jsr311 API somewhere on the classpath?

Comment: I do, but in provided scope:
org.jboss.resteasy:jaxrs-api:jar:2.1.0.GA:provided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you mentioned that it works with cxf 2.6.x but not with 2.7.x. So I think you should follow the migration guide http://cxf.apache.org/docs/27-migration-guide.html:

*JAX-RS endpoints in OSGI
    If you have compiled the application bundles against JSR-311 (JAX-RS 1.1) API and would like to get them running with CXF 2.7.x without recompiling against JSR-339 (JAX-RS 2.0) API then either
        have "javax.ws.rs", "javax.ws.rs.core" and "javax.ws.rs.ext" imported with the "[1.1, 3)" version range and use org.apache.servicemix.specs.jsr339-api-m10-2.1.0 spec bundle or
        use org.apache.servicemix.specs.jsr339-api-m10-2.2.0 spec bundle when it gets released.*

kind regards,
soilworker

Comment: I checked jboss built in modules and found that it has contains cxf 2.7.11 jars, so I thought that migration is not needed.

`$ find . -type f -name "*cxf*"
./system/layers/base/org/apache/cxf/main/cxf-api-2.7.11.redhat-3.jar
./system/layers/base/org/apache/cxf/impl/main/cxf-rt-transports-http-2.7.11.redhat-3.jar
...`

Comment: But your application works with 2.6.x. So, in my opinion, in the migration guide there should be the needed hints to for example an additionaly jsr-311.jar or something which causes the error you mentioned above.